# unexpected output in js code

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
console.log("typeof")
ann = eval(res[0].obj.one)(reqs.body.ans)
fun = eval(res[0].obj.one)
console.log(typeof(fun))
let anns = fun(reqs.body.ans)
console.log("value of function is")
console.log(ann)
console.log("ann")
console.log(anns)
```

this is my js code and res[0].obj.one is string and eval(res[0].obj.one) is function 
problem is when 
 i console.log(fun([1,2])) it give me expected ans but when i store it in variable and then print it then the ans is undefiend 

for example the above code output is

```
typeof
2.96006583845926
function
2.96006583845926
value of function is
undefined
ann
undefined
```

any help please may b it is node sync causing problem any solution please

simply i am giving value to variable after evaluating function but the variable value is not changing (it undefiend)

Comment: Would be good to know, what exactly `res[0].obj.one` has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be from the function your are trying to evaluate, in your log we can see **2.96006583845926** each time you eval it with a value, maybe it doesn't have a **return** value and only a console.log()?

Comment: thanku sir. you got super mind, u got my mistake. thanku thanku